# Remove First Name, Last Name and confirm password fields in account create page

Tags: magento, field

I searched a lot to remove required fields like `first name, Last name and confirm password`fields in account create page.
So far i renamed `required value from 1 to 0` from the table `eav_attribute`

After this i hided `first name, Last Name, Confirm Password` from `register.phtml`

But still i'm getting 
`The first name cannot be empty, The Last name cannot be empty, etc,..`

Did any one know how to do this ?

Please give me a idea to solve this..

Answer (score 2):

You have to change two more files:

Change /js/prototype/validation.js and comment out the following lines:

```
['validate-cpassword', 'Please make sure your passwords match.', function(v) {
                var conf = $('confirmation') ? $('confirmation') : $$('.validate-cpassword')[0];
                var pass = false;
                if ($('password')) {
                    pass = $('password');
                }
                var passwordElements = $$('.validate-password');
                for (var i = 0; i < passwordElements.size(); i++) {
                    var passwordElement = passwordElements[i];
                    if (passwordElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
                        pass = passwordElement;
                    }
                }
                if ($$('.validate-admin-password').size()) {
                    pass = $$('.validate-admin-password')[0];
                }
                return (pass.value == conf.value);
            }],
```

After that, you also have to change the Magento Customer Core model. There are two types of validation: through the front-end javascript and in the backend Customer model.
Rewrite the model with your own customer module. Then copy the validate() public function. And comment out the following lines:

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
        if ($password != $confirmation) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
        }
```